# How to merge datasets in a list by rows in R?

Tags: r

Similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229042/merging-a-data-frame-from-a-list-of-data-frames) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630024/combine-two-lists-in-a-dataframe-in-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295165/r-joining-merging-rows-in-one-dataset). However, none seem to help my specific situation. Im trying to merge a bunch of datasets (that are in a list) and turn it into a matrix. But Im trying to merge them by row. So, for example, if we have some data that looks like this:

```
set.seed(100)

dfList <- NULL
for(i in 1:3){
  dfList[[i]] <- data.frame(
    x1 = sample(1:10, 3, replace = T),
    x2 = sample(1:10, 3, replace = T)
    )
}

> dfList
[[1]]
  x1 x2
1 10  3
2  7  9
3  6 10

[[2]]
  x1 x2
1  7  4
2  6  7
3  6  6

[[3]]
  x1 x2
1  2  7
2  7  8
3  7  2
```

I am trying to merge the datasets by row and turn it into a matrix. What I mean is, the 1st row of my new matrix will come from the 1st row of the 1st data frame in the list. The 2nd row of my new matrix will come from the 1st row of the 2nd data frame in the list... and so on.

So, using the above example, my desired output would look like:

```
      x1 x2
 [1,] 10  3
 [2,]  7  4
 [3,]  2  7
 [4,]  7  9
 [5,]  6  7
 [6,]  7  8
 [7,]  6 10
 [8,]  6  6
 [9,]  7  2
```

Any suggestions as to how I could do this?

Comment: Have you tried rbindlist() in the data.table package?

Comment: I have but `rbindlist()` merges them in the same way `rbind` does. I'm not trying to `rbind` my data by merging the rows like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
library(tidyverse)
new_matrix <- lapply(seq_along(dfList),
                     function(x) {dfList[[x]] <- dfList[[x]] %>% mutate(id1 = 1:n(), id2 = x)}) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  arrange(id1, id2) %>%
  select(-id1, -id2) %>%
  as.matrix()



     x1 x2
 [1,] 10  3
 [2,]  7  4
 [3,]  2  7
 [4,]  7  9
 [5,]  6  7
 [6,]  7  8
 [7,]  6 10
 [8,]  6  6
 [9,]  7  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use abind like this:

```
library(abind)
nc <- ncol(dfList[[1]])
matrix(t(abind(dfList)), ncol = nc, byrow = TRUE)

giving:

      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   10    3
 [2,]    7    4
 [3,]    2    7
 [4,]    7    9
 [5,]    6    7
 [6,]    7    8
 [7,]    6   10
 [8,]    6    6
 [9,]    7    2
```

or with only  base R:

```
nc <- ncol(dfList[[1]])
matrix(t(do.call("cbind", dfList)), ncol = nc, byrow = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(dfList[[1]]), function(x){
  do.call(rbind, lapply(dfList, function(y) y[x,]))
  }))

   x1 x2
1  10  3
2   7  4
3   2  7
23  7  9
21  6  7
22  7  8
33  6 10
31  6  6
32  7  2
```

Achieves what you want assuming all `data.frames` have the same number of rows.

The rules are not clear in the question for the case where the number of rows may differ.

Answer (score 0):

Two other ways to order by row number after an `rbind`.

```r
set.seed(100)

dfList <- NULL
for(i in 1:3){
  dfList[[i]] <- data.frame(
    x1 = sample(1:10, 3, replace = T),
    x2 = sample(1:10, 3, replace = T)
    )
}

library(data.table)
rbindlist(dfList, idcol = 'x')[order(rowid(x)), -'x']
#>       x1    x2
#>    <int> <int>
#> 1:    10     3
#> 2:     7     4
#> 3:     2     7
#> 4:     7     9
#> 5:     6     7
#> 6:     7     8
#> 7:     6    10
#> 8:     6     6
#> 9:     7     2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

```r
set.seed(100)

dfList <- NULL
for(i in 1:3){
  dfList[[i]] <- data.frame(
    x1 = sample(1:10, 3, replace = T),
    x2 = sample(1:10, 3, replace = T)
    )
}

do.call(rbind, dfList)[order(unlist(lapply(dfList, function(x) seq(nrow(x))))),]
#>   x1 x2
#> 1 10  3
#> 4  7  4
#> 7  2  7
#> 2  7  9
#> 5  6  7
#> 8  7  8
#> 3  6 10
#> 6  6  6
#> 9  7  2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt -

```
library(dplyr)

lapply(dfList, asplit, 1) %>% purrr::transpose() %>% bind_rows()

#    x1    x2
#  <int> <int>
#1    10     3
#2     7     4
#3     2     7
#4     7     9
#5     6     7
#6     7     8
#7     6    10
#8     6     6
#9     7     2
```

If you need a matrix as output you can add `%>% as.matrix()` to the chain.